# Need understanding this Ruby Regex code

Tags: ruby, regex

I am attempting to become better acquainted with Ruby Regex and I came accros this in one of my codewars.com answers.

My current comprehension of this Regex is as follows. the `\W` means *any non-word character*. I am assuming that the *pipe* symbol means something to the effect of *between every character* and I think that the *underscore* means *all underscores between charecters*.

Am I even close? All criticism is welcomed. Thank you.

```
/\W|_/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the regex: `/\W|_/`, the vertical bar is just an "or". In Ruby, `_` is a word character (*e.g.*, `abc_def` is a valid *word* in Ruby), and is not matched with the `\W`. So the regex above matches a non-word character OR an underscore. You can test it out at [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/).

Comment: Good explanation, though I don't know why you say "Normally" and "considered".  As you know, the underscore is not a special character that needs to be escaped and, by "word character", you mean `'_'` matches `\w`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was thinking "outside of the Ruby box" a bit, not knowing the OP's programming background. I revised my wording for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're essentially correct. The regular expression token `\W` will match any non-word character. The pipe symbol — vertical bar is the [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) operator which  tells the regular expression engine to match either everything to the left of the alternation operator, or everything to the right which in this case you're matching either non-word characters or the literal character `_`.

You could make use of a character class here instead of using alternation:

```
/[\W_]/
```